# Can you work out the trial of wits without asking for a hint?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

POSSIBLE SPOILERS

**Question**

Is it possible to work out the first and third trials of wits (part of the Temple of Trials - see background for details) without resorting to trial-and-error, or the *other method*?

*Hover for "other method":*

> `The other method is asking the Monitor Bird for a hint`

Especially for the third trial, where there are a number of symbols with lines joining them up... I spent a long time looking in my wizarding companion at the various signs available to each familiar. I even got to the point of drawing matrices of possible symbols and then working through the permutations that each familiar had signs for...

After nearly two hours of struggling, I eventually gave up and resorted to the *other method*, after which I was able to solve the puzzle in under a minute.  But the solution seems completely random!

Is it possible to work this puzzle out? Is there a viable explanation for the solution, or is the *other method* actually the only method?

**Background**

*Hover for details on location of this puzzle in the game:*

> `The Temple of Trials is situated North East of Summerlands South and you go there after freeing Rashaad's daughter, Esther, from brokenheartedness.`

There are three trials, of which one is the Trial of Wits.

The trial of wits is made up of three rooms.  The second room is easy:

*Hover for second room solution:*

> `The second room is simply a picture puzzle - move the blocks to the appropriate place on the underlying picture so it doesn't look like there are any blocks at all.`

The first room has a maximum of 24 possible unique combinations, so it can be worked out through brute force if necessary.  However, as this is a trial of wits, I assume there must be a way to work out the puzzle without resorting to trial-and-error?

The third room has a maximum of 5,040 possible unique combinations and cannot therefore be worked out through a brute force method in *reasonable* time.

Comment: If you have unlimited attempts, bruteforce.

Comment: @kotekzot I've updated the question to include a section on brute-force attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method like you are looking for, the way I see it you have 3 possible options:

1. Ask for a hint
2. Brute force
3. Game Guide

The proper way to do it is to ask for a hint. What is misleading hear is the term "hint". I expect you are like me (and many other gamers) and view anything called "hint" as a short cut, and therefore it spoils your "perfect game" approach (regardless of the fact it has no effect).

I didn't want to take the "hint", so instead I found an on-line guide and looked up the "hint" but not the actual solution. This satisfied me enough - I was able to keep my hint count at zero whilst still feeling happy to have solved the puzzle myself.

Comment: "The proper way to do it..." Bah! I was afraid that would be the answer! As you say, I'm like you and many other gamers and prefer not to ask for help if there's a chance I can work something out for myself.  I was expecting the puzzles to be *puzzles*!  I suppose they are tests of wit; the sensible thing to do in this situation would be to ask for help.